# How to change public properties of User control?

Tags: asp.net

I have a very simple user control in my web site project which has public property declarations as following

```
    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _startDate;
        }
        set
        {
            _startDate = value;
        }
    }
    public DateTime EndDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _endDate;
        }
        set
        {
            _endDate = value;
        }
    }
```

When i drag the ascx file to one of my aspx page and when i go to code behind of aspx page i can access the controls properties through intelisense, but when i run the project through visual studio i get error "The name 'uctTest1' does not exist in the current context    " any suggetions to fix the error?

This is the line where Error shows when i run the project `uctTest.StartDate = DateTime.Now;`

aspx page markup :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="removetest.aspx.cs" Inherits="removetest" %>
<%@ Register src="~/uctTest.ascx" tagname="testCtl" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <uc1:testCtl ID="uctTest1" runat="server" />

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

aspx page code behind :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) 
    {
        uctTest1.StartDate = DateTime.Now;

    }
}
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: It might be more helpful if u posted the line of code where you are getting this error. The error doesnt seem to have anything to do with the public properties of the control itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another aspx page with different file name in the website project that another developer had copied from my aspx page which had same `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="aspxpagename.aspx.cs" Inherits="aspxpageClass" %>` directive in that copied page. Even though that copied paged didnt have user control strangely  page I was working reported the error. Changing that page directive's  codefile,inherits attributes to different values  fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing the @Register directive in the .aspx file referring to path of .ascx control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: NO i have the Register tag also <%@ Register src="uctTest.ascx" tagname="testCtl" tagprefix="uc1" %>